# $1$-cocycle associated to universal $G$-bundle $EG \to BG$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ be a (topological) group whose identity element $e_G$ is
a nondegenerated basepoint (e.g. if $G$ is a Lie group). Then that's a
known fact that there is for every 'nice' enough topological space $X$
(eg paracompact sp, or more elementary a CW complex)
a natural bijection

$$ [X, BG] \cong \mathcal{P}_G(X)  $$

between homotopy classes of cont maps $X \to BG$ and
isomorphism classes of of principal $G$-bundles over base $X$. Explicitely
this is given by associating to a homotopy class of a map
$f: X \to BG$ the pullback bundle $f^*EG$ of the *universal*
principal $G$-bundle $u:EG \to BG$.

Now like the trivial bundle the universal bundle $EG$ is the second
'canonical' (up to isomorphism) $G$-bundle and besides it's universal
property I'm trying to understand if it's possible to deduce it's
universal property *only* from study of it's *$1$-cocycle* represenation. Let's recall
that we can over every nice enough base space $X$ encode the complete information
about a $G$-bundle $E \to X$  with fiber $F$ (therefore $G \subset Aut(F)$;
in our case later it will be $G$ itself since we are interested on
principal bundles) in terms of a *$1$-cocycle*. Let $\mathcal{U}= \{U_i \}_i$ covering of $X$ over which $E$ trivializes, then

(1) a colection of homeomorphisms $\psi_i: U_i \times F \to p^{-1}(U_i)$ compatible
with projection $p$

(2) the *$1$-cycle* (ie the set of *transition functions*) $g_{ij}: U_j \cap U_i \to G$
such that for every $(x, f) \in (U_j \cap U_i) \times F$ we have

$$ \psi_j^{-1}  \circ \psi_i (x,f) = (x, (g_{ji}(x))(f))$$

(3) the transition functions satisfy $g_{ii} = e_G$ (constant function),
$g_{ji}= g_{ij}^{-1}$ and $g_{kj} \cdot g_{ji}= g_{ki}$

Moreover two $G$-bundles $E_1, E_2$ over same base $X$ are isomorphic
if there exist fine enough covering $\{U_i \}_i$ of $X$ such that
there eist a family $g_i: U_i \to G$ with

$$ g^2_{ij} = g_i \cdot g^1_{ij} \cdot g_j^{-1}  $$

where $\{g^1_{ij}\}$ and $\{g^2_{ij}\}$ are $1$-cycles of $E_1$ and $E_2$.

***Question***: Is it known which $1$-cocycle $\{g^{EG}_{ij}\}$ is naturally associated
to the universal bundle $u:EG \to BG$? Is there any canonical choice
of the covering $\{U_i \}_i$ of $BG$ known over which this
$1$-cocycle can be in most transparent way be declared? Is it known at least if we work with a
*finite group*? The model of $EG$ and $BG$ I have here in mind is that one
by Milnor explaned in detail for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523959/classifying-space-bg-and-contractable-space-eg).

If we work with this model for $EG \to BG$ can it's $1$-cocycle be
writen down? It must be something canonical but I don't know how
to determine it. My motivation is to understand if it's possible
to understand only by study the structure of it's $1$-cocycle that
this $G$-bundle is in certain way the most 'flexible' one in the sense
such that every other can be derived up to iso by the pullback of it,
as the universal property says. So speaking informally every 'twist' of $G$-bundle should be already 'known' in some way already to the universal bundle, such it 'knows' all possible twists can happen only by taking pullbacks. (Ok, I admit, that the last formulation is a bit vague, but that's the core of my motivation: I understand 'formally' the universal property of the universal bundle, but have no intuition on it's intrinsical geometry why and why exacly this geometry is the most 'flexible' to allow to recover all over $G$-bundles by taking pullbacks of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $x \in (0,1)$, I will define an open set $U_x$ of $BG$.

The way we can define it is by defining an open set $\tilde{U}_x$ of $EG$, stable under the action of $G$, with $|G|$ connected components that are permuted by the action of $G$. Then any one of these components will project to an open subset of $BG$.

The set $\tilde{U}_x$ in each simplex of $E_G$ by the condition that there exists some $i$ such that $\sum_{j< i} t_j < x$ and $\sum_{j \leq i } t_j > x$.  Because these are strict inequalities, this is an open subset of each simplex. Because they are unaffected by inserting a new $i$ with $t_i=0$, this remains open in $EG$. Because the tuple $g_1,\dots, g_n$ is not used in the definition, it is certainly stable under the action of $G$.

The connected components associated to $g\in G$ consists of those points where $g_i=g$ for the unique $i$ satisfying $\sum_{j< i} t_j < x$ and $\sum_{j \leq i } t_j > x$.  This is a component because the function $g_i$ is locally constant, because, on each simplex, the unique value of $i$ satisfying these inequalities is locally constant - it only changes at the points where $\sum_{j < i} t_i =x$ or $\sum_{j\leq i} t_i = x$, which are not in the set.

The open sets $U_x$ cover $BG$ (it suffices to take any infinite set of $x$) since at each point, such an $i$ exists for all but finitely many $x$.

The cocycle is defined as follows: Given a point in $BG$, expressed as a tuple $t_1,\dots, t_n$ of nonnegative reals summing to one and a tuple $g_1,\dots, g_n \in G$ modulo the left action of $G$, that lies in $U_x \cap U_y$, let $i_x$ be the unique $i$ such that $\sum_{j < i} t_i <x$ and $\sum_{j\leq i} t_i > x$, and define $i_y$ similarly, and then set $$\psi_{xy} ( ((t_1,\dots, t_n), (g_1,\dots, g_n)) =  g_{i_x}^{-1} g_{i_y} .$$

---

This cocycle is flexible in the sense that for *any* distinct tuple $x_1,\dots, x_n$ of open sets $U_{x_1},\dots, U_{x_n}$, for any tuple of $\psi_{ij} \in G$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$ such that $\psi_{ik} = \psi_{ij} \psi_{jk}$ for all $i,j,k$, there is a *unique* component of $U_{x_1} \cap \dots \cap U_{x_n}$ such that $\psi_{x_i x_j} $ restricted to this component is $\psi_{ij}$.

Indeed, such a tuple must have the form $\psi_{ij} = c_i^{-1} c_j$ for some tuple $c_i \in G$ for $i$ from $1$ to $n$, and then the component where $g_{i_{x_j}} = c_j$ for all $j$ does the trick.

---

But possibly this is not actually what you want to do. Probably you want to use a different cocycle presentation of $G$-bundles, the one where you fix a simplicial complex structure on the base, and present a cocycle as a tuple consisting of one element of $G$ for each edge satisfying one relation for each triangle.

For this one, the key point is that given a simplicial complex with such a cocycle, you can map it to BG by mapping each edge to the corresponding edge of $BG$, and then there will be a unique way of extending to triangles and then to higher simplices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One detail still confuses me. You define
the transition function $\psi_{xy}: U_x \cap U_y \to G$ as 
$\psi_{xy} ( ((t_1,\dots, t_n), (g_1,\dots, g_n)) =  g_{i_x}^{-1} g_{i_y}$. 
But isn't this family of transition functions defined in that way conjugated
via coboundary family' $\{ \psi_{U_x}\}$ with 
$\psi_{U_x}(((t_1,\dots, t_n), (g_1,\dots, g_n)):= g_{i_x}$
to the transtion family of constant functions $\{g_{UV}(x)= e_G \}$ which 
represent the trivial $G$-bundle $BG \times G$? But EG isnt trivial. Or do I confuse
some impotant aspect in your construction ?

Comment: @IsaktheXI It's not my construction - it's the construction of $BG$. The $g_1,\dots, g_n$ are only well-defined up to the action of $G$, so $g_{i_x}$ is not a well-defined function. It is on $EG$, which proves that this bundle is trivial on $EG$.

Comment: On your last 'But possibly...'. I think that this last paragraph in your
answer hits exactly my motivation behind study of these 
cycle representations.
Do I understand you correctly that
if we reduce our considerations to spaces which are simplicial complexes 
then all $G$-bundles over it can be always uniquely encoded
in these say 'discrete' $1$-cocycle versions associating to
every edge ${ij}$ (satisfying the relation you mentioned) between two vertices 
$a_i$ and $a_j$ a $g_{ij} \in G$?

Comment: Intuitively every vertex would then represent 
a disc (=local trivialization) around it over which the bundle trivializes and 
every edge (+relation) the intersection of such two discs?

Comment: And the special feature of $BG$ is that if we have 
such a $G$-bundle $E \to X$ with $X$ simplicial complex encoded
by such discrete cocycle $(..., g_{ij},...)$ then the $g_{ij}$ determine canonically
to which edge $B_{ij}$ of $B$ the edge $X_{ij}$ of $X$ should be mapped 
in order to obtain a map $X \to BG$ which pulls back $EG \to BG$ to 
bundle $E \to X$, that's the whole story? ...at least of for 
simplicial complexes. Did I understood this idea & philosophy using
'discrete' cocycles in this business around 'getting all $G$-principal bundles
via pullback' correctly?

Comment: @IsaktheXI Yeah, that sounds right to me. This idea of an open disc around each point works great when the edges all connect two distinct vertices (no loops) because otherwise an open ball around a vertex might make sense. It doesn't work for simplicial complexes like $BG$ that have loops, but it's still the case that every $G$-bundle can be encoded as a discrete $1$-cocycle, unique up to the obvious symmetry (maps from the set of vertices to $G$).

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: when you are talking about an edge (of a simplicial 
complex) 'satisfying one relation for each triangle' do you 
mean just by this 'one' relation simply the identification of this edge
as one the boundaries of a triangle, nothing more? So as a simple example
if we have a loop (=edge with same initial & final point) then
since this identification of these two points would then require 
an additional *separate* relation, and so these edges as indices of discrete $1$-cocycles we discard, that's
the message, right?

Comment: About your last sentence in your last comment I'm a bit confused. You wrote that the 
simplicial model of $BG$ is such example of a space with only
loop edges, but on the other hand that it is still true that every $G$-bundle  can
nevertheless encoded as *discrete* $1$-cycles (unique up symmetry)
So especially - as far as I understand you - also bundles over spaces
like $BG$, right?

Comment: Could you explain how you associate such discrete $1$-cycle in 
that case? The construction from your last paragraph seems to fail
(as far as I understand correctly what you mean by an
edge 'satisfying one relation for each triangle') since as you explaned
$BG$ would then have only loops as edges. How you associate in that
case a discrete $1$-cycle to a $G$-bundle over $BG$?

Comment: @IsaktheXI The edge doesn't satisfy one relation for each triangle, it's the cocycle that satisfies one relation for each triangle. All relations are of the form $g_2 g_2 =g_3$ where $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are the elements of the groups associated to the three edges of a triangle. There is no relation for an edge that is loop.  For example, a simplicial complex containing one vertex, one edge forming a loop, and no higher simplices, a one-cocycle is just an element of $g$, and two 1-cocycles $g,g'$ are equivalent iff $g' = h g h^{-1}$ for some $h \in G$. (This is what I called the "obvious symmetry".)

Comment: The general recipe to associated a discrete $1$-cycle to a $G$-bundle is to fix a trivialization over each vertex and then for each edge extend the trivialization at one vertex over the edge to the other vertex and then compare with the trivialization at the other vertex to get an element of $G$. This works as well on $BG$ as any other space.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand the construction now and also what caused my confusion. 
In your comment from yesterday you meant just that 
*my proposed approach using discs around vertices* as local trivialization might
not always work (due to eg this 'loop pathology'), but *for the 
method to obtain a discrete cocycle* you described in your last comment 
such loops don't cause any problems, right? So the problem there was simply a
'bad' choice of a trivialization in that case?

Comment: @IsaktheXI Yes. The only pathology with loops is that discs around the vertices no longer given an open cover - there is really no difficulty with the trivialization. The problems is that if our discs overlap themselves.. If we modify the definition of an open cover to allow open sets to overalp themselves - i.e. we allow what in algebraic geometry is called an etale cover - then there is no problem, and the trivialization step goes through. (Slogan: Trivializations are easy, open covers are hard.)

Comment: Alright, thank you for explanations... and patience :)

Comment: there is still a point in the construction of
the open sets $\bar{U}_x$ confusing me a bit. 
By definition the points of $\bar{U}_x$ which 
are contained in an choosen $k$-simplex $S_k$
are exactly those for which there exist 
a $0 \le i \le k$ such that a point 
$(t_0,t_1,..., t_k)$ of this fixed
$k$-simplex lies in $\bar{U}_x$ if and only if
$\sum_{j< i} t_j < x$ and $\sum_{j \leq i } t_j > x$.
I'm still brood about the choice of this
$i$ for every simplex. Are these $i$ unique for
every fixed $x$ and $k$-simplex $S_k$ or
are choices involved?

Comment: From the definition
there seems to me that there is no reason why 
this $i$ should be 
unique. Do you make
here for every pair $(x, S_k)$ 
an explicit choice for $i=i(\bar{U}_x, S_k)$ 
satisfying the inequalities or does the construction
of $\bar{U}_x$  
intrinsically contain a constrain which urges
necessarily the $i$ to be unique, such that
there not really any choices for every 
simplex? If the second it the case, why?

Comment: In third paragraph you identify the connected composents
of $\bar{U}_x$ to $g$ to those points where
$g=g_i$ for a unique $i$. Here the $i$ comes 
seemingly in unique way.  Could you clarify this point?

Comment: @IsaktheXI Such $i$ are unique since if $i,i'$ both satisfy these inequalities with (wlog) $i<i'$ then $x< \sum_{j \leq i} t_j  \leq \sum_{j <i'} t_j < x$, a contradiction.